# Create a separator between viewcontrollers in UIPageViewControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, yahoo, uipageviewcontroller

**Background:** I am trying to create an app which looks a little like Yahoo Weather App. In that app, you may add more than 1 locations. You can swipe left and right to get to a new location. While you are swiping there is a clear black separator between the two location views (more than 1 pixel thick).

**Problem:** I can only create a separator which also appears as a black boarder around my stationary view, if I were to get a separator. Otherwise, The views are connected without and indicator.

**Question:** How do I make separator, without adding boarder to my view controllers.(ie padding between viewcontrollers)

*Current*
[image]

*Want*
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your page view controller's container:

```
NSDictionary* options = @{ UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0f] };

self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] 
                            initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll 
                            navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal 
                            options:options];
```

- [dox](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Options_Keys)